# Drupal Site was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet

Tags: drupal-7

I am getting the following issue when I converted HTTP to https in Drupal

> Site was loaded with HTTPS but requested an insecure stylesheet 
>   'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:regular&subset=cyrillic-ext'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Thanks in advance

Comment: change http:// to https://.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can we change it from drupal admin panel without touching core files.

Comment: which module is adding that stylesheet ?

Comment: Google api Module in Drupal

Comment: Sorry its Google Font API module

Comment: If you are using the following Module https://www.drupal.org/project/google_fonts it wont cause any problem. As the link is converted to https by the module itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Everyone, I added

```php
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'
```

in settings.php file and http converted to https

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer might work for some, it didn't work for me on Drupal core version 9.5.

Adding below Apache directive in the site's root `.htaccess` file did the trick

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Originally answered at https://www.drupal.org/project/securelogin/issues/1670822#comment-13000601

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).